# Laravel Remove All Records One Week Old

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, delete-row

I want to create a cron job which fires off a task/command in Laravel to remove all records which are 1 week old. I am trying to use ExpressiveDate to help me out to evaluate the time. What is the best way in Laravel to do this?

I have registered the command:

```
Artisan::add(new removeWeek);
```

And created a removeWeek.php command under /apps/command and that works fine. I am looking for the best syntax -an eloquent way- to traverse my records and only remove records a week old from the current day. The cron job will run once a day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have all set, so now you just have to

```
Calendar::where('created_at', '<', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subWeek())->delete();
```

One last thing: classes names are conventionally Capitalized:

```
class RemoveWeek() {

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The laravel way to remove records periodically is by using the trait `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Prunable`

This will help you to delete models that are no longer needed by implementing the `prunable` method which returns an Eloquent query builder that resolves the models to remove.

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Prunable;

class Post extends Model
{
    use Prunable;

    /**
     * Get the prunable model query.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function prunable()
    {
        return static::where('created_at', '<=', now()-> subWeek());
    }
}
```

Then run the command:

```
php artisan model:prune
```

Of course you can schedule the `model:prune` artisan command to run periodically

Here is the link for documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#pruning-models